# finding solutions by using the discriminant

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The path of a dolphin as it leaps out of the water can be modeled by the equation 
$h = -0.4d^{2} + d$, where h is the dolphin’s height above water and $d$ is the horizontal distance 
from its starting point. Both $h$ and $d$ are in metres.

Find the greatest height the dolphin reaches during a leap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the discriminant is $0$, the equation only has one real root. So you want to find a height $h_{max}=-C$ such that the discriminant is $0$.

So $B^2-4AC=0 \Leftrightarrow 1-(4)(-.04)C=0$

$\therefore C=-\frac{1}{1.6} \Leftrightarrow h=\frac{1}{1.6}=.625$ meters.

For intuition, we are basically translating down the parabola formed by $Ax^2+Bx \equiv0.4d^2+d$ down by $C$, so that it only hits the $x$ axis once. In doing so, we find $h_{max}$.

EDIT: To find the horizontal distance the dolphin travels to maximize its height without using calculus, set our new translated parabola equal to $0$ and solve for $d$. So $-.4d^2+d-.625=0$. Solving for $d$ with the quadratic formula and taking the positive value yields $d=1.25$.

Comment: yeah thanks~ i found the answer is 0.625 meters too. but the answer for this is actually 1.25 meters

Comment: That would be the horizontal distance the dolphin travels until it reaches its maximum height! Your question asks for the "greatest height."

Comment: @harry Would you instead like me to explain how to find the horizontal distance that maximizes height?

Comment: Yesh please ^_^

Comment: I'll edit it in. :)